# How to have multiple autocomplete elements with selection independent of each other

Tags: angular, mat-autocomplete

I am working on a Angular application. I have stackblitz demo that shows one matautocomplete with multiple select enabled but in my application I have array of matautocomplete I want option selected from one element not to interfere with another element. How to do this?

For example if I select option1 inside the first element I see option1 is getting selected in other eleemnts as well. I don't want this o happen instead I want them to be independent of each other.

Here is the stackblitz demo [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sx79hu)

Comment: Your stackblitz does not really show the problem you are describing as it contains only one autocomplete.
However, I think your problem might be related to storing the checkbox state in your User object. If you have the other autocompletes using the same array of Users, then they will also have the same checkbox state.

Comment: Exactly  I want to find a solution for this

Comment: I tried to storing it in a array but I was not able to do it